# Populating Objects from Data base POO

Tags: php, database, static

I have a question regarding how to populate objects from the Data base, it's more about the architecture than populating it self.

Let's say I have a table called receipts which has: receipt_id, user_id, issue_date, business_id, product_id abd type.

Now I want to create a Receipt class which will be populated from that table, I would do something like this:

```
class Receipt {


public function __construct($receipt_id = null) {
    if(!is_null($receipt_id))
        $this->populate($receipt_id);
}

public function populate($receipt_id){
    //Get data from data base
}

public function save(){
    //Saves the current receipt into the data base.
}

public static function getReceiptsFromUser($user_id){

}
```

}

My question is about getReceiptsFromUser, should it be static?. It makes sense for the User class to have a method called getReceipts which would return an array of receipts objects calling this static method. I think it should be static because it doesn't make any sense to create an empty receipt to generate the user's receipts. Is there any flaws in this architecture or better aproaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be static. As you already mentioned yourself, you don't need a Receipt object in order to retrieve other Receipts.

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class.

By the way, what you're doing here is called the [Active Record pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). If you're going to use this approach, it's a good idea to create a base class (you can call it `Record` or something similar) that defines the shared methods (such as `save`, `find`, etc.) and let your models extend them (`class Receipt extends Record`, `class User extends Record`, etc.). This way, you don't need to repeat this code in all of your models.

A nice (PHP) example for this approach is given by the [PHP ActiveRecord project](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/). A look into their documentation should give you some ideas about how it works.

Another approach is the [Data Mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). The benefit is that your models don't know anything about how they're being saved, so you have great flexibility in how you want to persist your data, instead of being tied to the limitations of ActiveRecord.